# jQuery One Page Scroll in wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to code wordpress template with [jquery one page scroll plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html). Can someone help me to understand why the plugin is not working when I add it to my template using functions.php file like this:

```
  function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()  {
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'one-page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js' , '', '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'front', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'one-page' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'front' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

After including it to footer.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bootstrap/js/front.js"></script>
```

plugin works. But I rather want to use the first method than second one. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with functions.php?

Comment: can you see them echoed and linked properly in source?

Comment: yup. Everything's good in page source

Comment: is the sequence same in footer too? is jquery loaded before these files?

Comment: yes. same like quoted before.

Comment: i would like to see the page (having enqueue method)

Answer (score 1):

add `true` at the end to add it to the bottom of the script before the closing `body` tag

```
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_register_script( 'one-page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_register_script( 'front', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery.onepage-scroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
```